# C# interview question

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is an interview question I need help with.

You have the following ASP.NET code-behind class:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page 
{
    private string _value;

    public Page1() 
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Ticks % 10 == 0)
            _value = "Test";
    }       

    ~Page1() 
    {
        if(_value.Equals("Test"))
            _value = string.Empty;      
    }
}
```

Any time someone requests this page, the `w3wp.exe` process terminates unexpectedly.

- Why does this occur versus the user seeing a yellow screen of death (default ASP.NET error page)?
- Why is there always an OutOfMemoryException present on the managed heap?

Comment: quick? Are you in the interview right now?

Comment: And if Ticks % 10 != 0 _value will be null.  You dereferenced it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hint: never throw exceptions in a destructor/finalizer or you will kill the thread on which the GC runs and without GC things might get ugly.

While there was some tolerance in .NET 1.1 towards exceptions thrown in background threads which were consumed and wouldn't bring the hosting process down that's no longer the case starting from CLR 2.0. [Quote from the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx):

> If Finalize or an override of Finalize
>   throws an exception, and the runtime
>   is not hosted by an application that
>   overrides the default policy, the
>   runtime terminates the process and no
>   active try-finally blocks or
>   finalizers are executed. This behavior
>   ensures process integrity if the
>   finalizer cannot free or destroy
>   resources.

Throwing an exception in a finalizer is fatal.